# Spring Scheduled Services in multi module project

Tags: java, spring

I have a multi-module project which is set up like this:

```
commons-module
  -CommonsApp.java (Main class)
  -CommonsService.java
api-module
  -ApiApp.java (Main class)
main-moudle
  -MainApp.java (Main class)
  -MainService.java
```

Both *CommonsService* and *MainService* have some business logic and both have a corresponding *@Scheduled* annotated method to perform some batch processing.

*MainService* has a dependency on *CommonsService* and it autowires it inside main-module.

My app will run on seperate VM instances, with each module's jar running on its own instance.
If I make the *commons-module* a dependency of *main-module* to autowire the beans from it, I worry that the MainApp.java will also start running the scheduled methods of commons-module(CommonsService.java).

This way there would be a huge wastage of resources as those scheduled methods will be running on both the *commons-module* machine and the *main-module* machine.

So how can I ensure that I use the *CommonsService.java* in *main-module* without letting Spring execute the *@Scheduled* annotated methods in it?

Comment: I would suggest to extract the scheduled method(s) in its own module. Here you can have dependencies to other modules, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `ShedLock`
ShedLock does one and only one thing. It makes sure your scheduled tasks are executed at most once at the same time.
[github link](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)